# Debugging javascript using firebug

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to debug following javascript program using firebug in firefox

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Debug: Times Table 2</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function writeTimesTable(timesTable) 
        {
            var counter;
            var writeString;
            for (counter = 1; counter < 12; counter++) 
            {
                writeString = counter + " * " + timesTable + " = ";
                writeString = writeString + (timesTable * counter);
                writeString = writeString + "<br />";
                document.write(writeString);
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var timesTable;
        for (timesTable = 1; timesTable <= 12; timesTable++) 
        {
            document.write("<p>")
            writeTimesTable(timesTable)
            document.write("</p>")
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When i set breakpoint at second for loop and reload browser reload page without halting execution . But in chrome using web inspector it works perfectly fine

what's wrong

Comment: You can not just write opening and closing tags, it does not work like you are building a string! That opening and closing paragraph tags do not do what you think they do.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Open firefox and enable firebug

**2)** Open your HTML page in Firefox.

**3)** GO to ***script*** tab of the firebug console

**4)** If there is a message ***"Reload"*** then click reload and load all the javascript code

**5)** Click on the line numbers you want to set ***breakpoints*** on, as many as you want

**6)** In the same tab, on the right side of the header, click on ***play*** icon to go through your **breakpoints**

**Note:** I just debugged your code successfully in firebug.

Comment: try to set breakpoint in second for loop and reload page it won't halt

Comment: Huh, that is interesting. I hope firebug does not treat script inside body tag untouchable and hence ignoring it.